# What type of bug is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Found two larva/eggs in a suitcase. The egg/larva were around same size or maybe little bigger than a grain of rice. When I put them on counter top to better examine, one hatched and a SINGLE insect popped out! It was fast moving when hatched and kept cleaning its legs. It was maybe the size of a grain of rice. I personally was thinking cockroach but it was a single insect from egg/larva!?!? Is it a bed bug or something else??? (We reside in Alabama.)

https://share.icloud.com/photos/0mQiO0JfeRwR3z7duvPSthrZw
[image][image]

Comment: If you have the photo on your device, use the mountain symbol to put the photo directly in your question

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should include: 1) one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible) — photos must be uploaded (not links); 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information; and 4) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: In addition, there is an excellent post with information about bed bugs already on this site. If that is your primary concern please search on this site for "bed bug" and then delete this duplicate post if that answers your question.

Comment: I edited post as instructed. And also searched “bed bug” as instructed  Still left with question... Any advice on bug type? Comments? Please help...

Comment: From the evidence at hand, we can say Order Diptera (two-winged flies) with certainty; the suborder Brachycera seems more likely (the antennae of the adult in closeup are very short; Nematoceran flies usually would have antennae at least as long as the head is wide [those that don't bear NO resemblance to the OP photo]); beyond that, there are too many good possibilities (members of the family Drosophilidae [the geneticist's "fruit fly"] being just one of many possible groups).